# How can I make a new Array and copy all the postive elements from the other array in the new array and return it?

Tags: java, arrays, element

This method returns an array that contains the positive elements of the parameter array in.
To do that, compute the number of positive elements in the array in and store the obtained value in the variable
nElements of type integer, declare the double array output of size nElements, copy the positive elements
of in into the array output, and return the array output. If all the elements of the array in are non-positive,
your method should return an array of size 1 and the only element of the returned array is assigned the
value -1.

My question here is when I run my program it states Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException and I don't know how to take it out and only return the positive elements.

The Java-Code:

```
public static double [] partialPositiveArray(double [] in)

   {

   int nElements = 0;

   for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
   {
     if(in[i] > 0)
     {
        nElements = (int)in[i];

     }
     else if(in[i] <= 0)
     {
        nElements = -1;
     }
  }
  double [] output = new double[nElements];


  for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
  {
     output[i] = nElements;

  }

  return output;

  }
```

Comment: the fail ist in this line: `nElements = -1;`. Change it to `nElements -= 1;` or `nElements = nElements - 1;` then you become no error but just a storage address of an object. but you want all positiv numbers from the array **in** added, right?

Comment: Yes I want all positive numbers

Comment: and with the negative numbers you don't want do anything?

Comment: just returned -1 from the new array

Comment: for example, if it has 3 negative numbers, do you want 3 entries in the new array, each with -1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with this code you will add all positive numbers. the sum in this example is 60.7 and for all negative numbers it will write -1 in the negative-array. in this example twice.

**Code:**

```
public class NegativeAndPositiveNumbers {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] arr = {25.0, -7.0, 10.7, 25.0, -64.0};
        System.out.println(partialPositiveArray(arr));

        int negative[] = negativeArray(arr);
        for (int i = 0; i < negative.length; i++){
            System.out.print(negative[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static double partialPositiveArray(double[] in) {
        double nElements = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            if (in[i] > 0) {
                nElements += in[i];
            }
        }
        return nElements;
    }

    public static int[] negativeArray(double[] in) {
        int[] negativeWithZero = new int[in.length];
        int index = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            if (in[i] <= 0) {
                negativeWithZero[index] = -1;
                index++;
            }
        }
        int[] negative = new int[index];

        for (int j = 0; j < negative.length; j++){
            negative[j] = negativeWithZero[j];
        }

        return negative;
    }
}
```

I think it could be solved more easily, but it works anyway. I hope everything is clear

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the variable nElements when it is positive you are taking the value from in[ ] array and when it is negative you are changing it to -1.

```
for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
       {
         if(in[i] > 0)
         {
            nElements = (int)in[i];

         }
         else if(in[i] <= 0)
         {
            nElements = -1;
         }
      }
```

In the array you are passing to the function there seems to be a negative number at end so when control comes across this ,nElements value is -1. After the loop you are instantiating an array with size given as this variable

`double [] output = new double[nElements`];

Therefore you are getting  NegativeArrayIndexException

Solution as per requirement:

```
 public static double [] partialPositiveArray(double [] in)
       {

        boolean gotPositive=false;
        int size=0;
        int j=0;
        for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
        {
         if(in[i] >= 0)
         {
            size++;
            gotPositive=true;
         }
       }
       if(size==0 && !gotPositive){
           size=1;
       }
       double [] output = new double[size];
       for(int i = 0; i < in.length; i++)
       {
         if(in[i] >= 0)
         {
            output[j++]=in[i];
         }
      }
      if(!gotPositive){
          output[0]=-1;
      }
      return output;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double [] partialPositiveArray(double [] in) {
    return Arrays.stream(in)
                 .filter(d -> d > 0)
                 .toArray();
}
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn, and apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback from users in the form of upvotes, when the code is explained.